# error: code too large in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

i have  problem with netbeans. plz help
the error is

```
error: code too large
private void initComponents() {

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post your complete related code to clarify your doubts! Present piece of code is of no help.

Comment: @shekharsuman: if it's too large to compile, it's also probably too large to be posted here :-)

Comment: in my app i need to add more than 200 jlabel but now i can't add any jlabel the problem is in  initComponents()

Comment: 200 jlabel? Split single method into multiple ones based on group of functionality, very bad idea to have 200 jlabel in single method.

Comment: the problem ..the code is generated code ..i don't know how to make it in group

Answer (score 2):

Your method is too large to be compiled. A method can not contain more than 64KB of bytecode.

Since it seems this is code generated by NetBeans to add and layout GUI components to a panel or a JFrame, you should split your GUI into several, independant sub-panels, instead of trying to put everything into a single one.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,,yes i tried to do  the sub-panels but am afraid if the code change or something happen to  code